# Ruby 1.9.3. CSV - Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, gmail

I did my research, but none of the solutions seems to work for my case.
I had a gmail format csv, exported from gmail itself. My parsing code is simple as that:

```
CSV.open(file.path) do |csv|
```

Error is:

```
Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n
```

I tried combinations of `row_sep`, `encoding`, but none of them helps. Any thoughts?

Ruby file read returned:

```
ruby -e 'p File.read("tmp/google.csv")'       

"\xFF\xFEN\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000G\u0000i\u0000v\u0000e\u0000n\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000A\u0000d\u0000d\u0000i\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000a\u0000l\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000F\u0000a\u0000m\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000Y\u0000o\u0000m\u0000i\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000G\u0000i\u0000v\u0000e\u0000n\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000 \u0000Y\u0000o\u0000m\u0000i\u0000,\u0000A\u0000d\u0000d\u0000i\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000a\u0000l\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000 \u0000Y\u0000o\u0000m\u0000i\u0000,\u0000F\u0000a\u0000m\u0000i\u0000l\u0000y\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000 \u0000Y\u0000o\u0000m\u0000i\u0000,\u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000 \u0000P\u0000r\u0000e\u0000f\u0000i\u0000x\u0000,\u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000 \u0000S\u0000u\u0000f\u0000f\u0000i\u0000x\u0000,\u0000I\u0000n\u0000i\u0000t\u0000i\u0000a\u0000l\u0000s\u0000,\u0000N\u0000i\u0000c\u0000k\u0000n\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000S\u0000h\u0000o\u0000r\u0000t\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000M\u0000a\u0000i\u0000d\u0000e\u0000n\u0000 \u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000,\u0000B\u0000i\u0000r\u0000t\u0000h\u0000d\u0000a\u0000y\u0000,\u0000G\u0000e\u0000n\u0000d\u0000e\u0000r\u0000,\u0000L\u0000o\u0000c\u0000a\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000,\u0000B\u0000i\u0000l\u0000l\u0000i\u0000n\u0000g\u0000 \u0000I\u0000n\u0000f\u0000o\u0000r\u0000m\u0000a\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000,\u0000D\u0000i\u0000r\u0000e\u0000c\u0000t\u0000o\u0000r\u0000y\u0000 \u0000S\u0000e\u0000r\u0000v\u0000e\u0000r\u0000,\u0000M\u0000i\u0000l\u0000e\u0000a\u0000g\u0000e\u0000,\u0000O\u0000c\u0000c\u0000u\u0000p\u0000a\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000,\u0000H\u0000o\u0000b\u0000b\u0000y\u0000,\u0000S\u0000e\u0000n\u0000s\u0000i\u0000t\u0000i\u0000v\u0000i\u0000t\u0000y\u0000,\u0000P\u0000r\u0000i\u0000o\u0000r\u0000i\u0000t\u0000y\u0000,\u0000S\u0000u\u0000b\u0000j\u0000e\u0000c\u0000t\u0000,\u0000N\u0000o\u0000t\u0000e\u0000s\u0000,\u0000G\u0000r\u0000o\u0000u\u0000p\u0000 \u0000M\u0000e\u0000m\u0000b\u0000e\u0000r\u0000s\u0000h\u0000i\u0000p\u0000,\u0000E\u0000-\u0000m\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000 \u00001\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000T\u0000y\u0000p\u0000e\u0000,\u0000E\u0000-\u0000m\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000 \u00001\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000V\u0000a\u0000l\u0000u\u0000e\u0000,\u0000E\u0000-\u0000m\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000 \u00002\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000T\u0000y\u0000p\u0000e\u0000,\u0000E\u0000-\u0000m\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000 \u00002\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000V\u0000a\u0000l\u0000u\u0000e\u0000,\u0000P\u0000h\u0000o\u0000n\u0000e\u0000 \u00001\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000T\u0000y\u0000p\u0000e\u0000,\u0000P\u0000h\u0000o\u0000n\u0000e\u0000 \u00001\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000V\u0000a\u0000l\u0000u\u0000e\u0000,\u0000W\u0000e\u0000b\u0000s\u0000i\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u00001\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000T\u0000y\u0000p\u0000e\u0000,\u0000W\u0000e\u0000b\u0000s\u0000i\u0000t\u0000e\u0000 \u00001\u0000 \u0000-\u0000 \u0000V\u0000a\u0000l\u0000u\u0000e\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000\u0010\u0004;\u00045\u0004:\u0004A\u00040\u0004=\u00044\u0004@\u0004,\u0000\u0010\u0004;\u00045\u0004:\u0004A\u00040\u0004=\u00044\u0004@\u0004,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000*\u0000 \u0000M\u0000y\u0000 \u0000C\u0000o\u0000n\u0000t\u0000a\u0000c\u0000t\u0000s\u0000 \u0000:\u0000:\u0000:\u0000 \u0000*\u0000 \u0000F\u0000r\u0000i\u0000e\u0000n\u0000d\u0000s\u0000,\u0000*\u0000 \u0000O\u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000r\u0000,\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000r\u0000s\u0000h\u0000y\u0000n\u0000i\u0000n\u0000@\u0000g\u0000m\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000.\u0000c\u0000o\u0000m\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000,\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000"
```

It's seems that google files had a strange encoding:

```
enca tmp/google.csv                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Universal character set 2 bytes; UCS-2; BMP
  CRLF line terminators
  Byte order reversed in pairs (1,2 -> 2,1)
```

File content:

```
Name,Given Name,Additional Name,Family Name,Yomi Name,Given Name Yomi,Additional Name Yomi,Family Name Yomi,Name Prefix,Name Suffix,Initials,Nickname,Short Name,Maiden Name,Birthday,Gender,Location,Billing Information,Directory Server,Mileage,Occupation,Hobby,Sensitivity,Priority,Subject,Notes,Group Membership,E-mail 1 - Type,E-mail 1 - Value,E-mail 2 - Type,E-mail 2 - Value,Phone 1 - Type,Phone 1 - Value,Website 1 - Type,Website 1 - Value
Александр,Александр,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,* My Contacts ::: * Friends,* Other,starshynin@gmail.com,,,,,,
```

Comment: may be the content of file will help us to reproduce it and then some fix..

Comment: @ArupRakshit i added file content, i assume i need to change encoding.

Comment: Ok.. what's the output of `puts Encoding.default_external` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit it's UTF-8

Comment: Can you try this `CSV.open(file.path, "rb:UCS-2:UTF-8") do |csv|..` ? Let me know the result

Comment: @ArupRakshit `OS X` result is `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

Comment: Are you only reading this file ?

Comment: I'm reading a lot of csv's, and all of them works perfectly, i have only problem with this particular csv from google. In this request i'm reading only one file.
I'm ran `CharlockHolmes::EncodingDetector.detect(f.read)` on this file and the result is:
`{:type=>:binary, :confidence=>100}`
Also google has two options how to export csv file: google csv format and outlook csv format. The second option works great, i believe it's somehow related with how google formatting their csv, really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to specify the encoding when opening the file. Try using something like this until you manage to decode the file:

```
File.open(file.path, "rb:UTF-16BE").read.encode("utf-8")
```

The encoding of your file seems to be UTF-16, so try UTF-16, UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE.

After that you can try to feed the encoded data into a CSV reader like this:

```
CSV.open(File.open(file.path, "rb:UTF-16BE")) do |csv|
```

and process the file. You may need to re-encode the data into UTF-8 at some point. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: I'm able to read csv with encoding, but unfortunately file is always malformed after encoding `#<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:1>`.

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin Which encoding you used ?

Comment: Okay, got it working like this:
`File.open(file.tempfile, "rb:UTF-16") do |f|`
`csv = CSV.parse(f.read, :headers => true)`
But usual files that not  utf-16(ucs-2) not working with this approach, how to make this optional, because ruby returns `<Encoding:UTF-8>` for utf-16 and non-utf-16 files.

Comment: https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes this gem returns correct encoding `UTF-16LE`, while ruby says UTF-8

Comment: If you are not sure what encoding is your input you need to use some gem like charlock_holmes to detect it. There is no universal way for this and it could be a tough task. You can also check out https://rubygems.org/gems/rchardet19